# A paper of N. Jochnowitz

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Can some one provide the following paper :

**Congruences between modular forms of half integral weights and implications for class numbers and elliptic curves**.
It was mentionned by many authers ( K.Ono, J.Bruinier...)

Comment: This paper does not seem to be freely available, so you need to go to a library, use interlibrary loan, use a subscription, or contact the author directly. At any rate, such requests are off-topic here.

Comment: @GHfromMO: I'mpretty sure this paper was never published, which eliminates all the library-based options and leaves contacting the author.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg: Thanks for the clarification. I have not checked MathSciNet before making my comment, but I should have.

Comment: I am sorry: as Steven Landsburg said, this paper was never published. So my advice is to contact the author or someone who has quoted this paper. See http://www.sas.rochester.edu/mth/people/faculty/jochnowitz-naomi/index.html